# How to develop a custom protractor locator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I have an angular-application where I put custom html-attributes ("`data-testid='saveButton'`") for identification on e.g. buttons, inputs etc.
Protractor has no built-in locator for this: the xpath-way does not work as this will always search from the document root (to overcome this limitation I would have to do quite a lot of string-magic to build the xpath-string, so I discarded this variant).

So I wanted to write my own locator, and consulted the official [Protractor Documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator).

The documentation leaves me with an important question:
What methods are available on the parent-element-object? In their example they use `using.querySelectorAll('button');` but how do they know they can use this?

I searched for 'querySelectorAll' in the protractor-documentation to see if it is maybe a method of `ElementFinder` or `WebElement`, but I didn't find it.

Also I found no way to debug the locator (only stop the protractor-test by `browser.pause()`), so I can't look at runtime to see what I can do with the given parent-element.

So does anybody know how I can get information about what methods the parent-element has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parent-element`, which is essentially the context of the selector is a DOM element that gets handled by the browser - it can use whatever DOM function there is, in this case [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll). As the addLocator's example says about the function you pass to it:

> This function will be serialized as a string and will execute in the browser.

Also, keep in mind that there is a way to provide context to the xpath selectors thus avoiding the search from root:

```
var context = element(by.css('.some-parent-element-class'));
var divDirectDescendants = context.element(by.xpath('div'));
var divAllDescendants = context.element(by.xpath('.//div'));
```

With CSS these would be:

```
var divDirectDescendants = element(by.css('.some-parent-element-class > div'));
var divAllDescendants = element(by.css('.some-parent-element-class  div'));
```

Also, there's a way to achieve what you want with a [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) (which is what `querySelectorAll` is, after all):

```
var everyElementWithMyAttr = element.all(by.css('[data-testid="saveButton"]'));
```

Comment: Yes, if you put `//` at the front, it would start from root; otherwise it respects the context, so `.//` is working fine if you have a context. Now, if you run `element(by.xpath('.//div'))` directly the context would be the root element and would behave that way, but `context.element(by.xpath('.//div')` works fine.

Comment: sry, i deleted my comment while you were answering because after writing it i saw the "." For documentation purposes: i thought the xpath-selector did not respect context, and would search only from root.